# Objective-C: is there any leaks?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

`currentSettings` - ivar

`settings` - method's parameter

here is the method which usually executed many times. ARC is enabled.

```
currentSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
currentSettings = settings;
```

is there something wrong in this code?

Comment: With ARC, there's no leak, but you're creating and then immediately throwing away a dictionary every time these two lines run. Under MRR it would leak.

Comment: You should run “Analyze” in Xcode, which will tell you if there is any leaks or not in your code. For your information, for this code, using ARC, you don’t have any leaks. In between the first and the second line, the compiler will insert a release of the dictionary in the first line.

Comment: lemme guess -- the tutsplus tutorial again?  Yeah, don't use that.  There is no need to "initialize the pointer" by assigning an empty, freshly created, dictionary to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No leaks, this would only leak if ARC wasn't enabled (because then you would loose the pointer to the created `NSMutableDictionary`). But because ARC is enabled, you are simply allocating and deallocating a dictionary superfluously, since the `currentSettings` instance variable will release its previous value when a new one is set.

All in all, you don't need the first line. Instance variables are `strong` by default, so it will take care of (retain) the method argument.

Comment: A little asterisk on the instance variables being strong - properties declared with weak will have synthesized ivars which are also `__weak`, so be careful when dealing with weak properties and iVars.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That's right. I assumed there's no corresponding property for this ivar, since OP didn't mention there is one.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's allright - there is no property, just ivar. Thanks for the good explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is creating a new dictionary that is then thrown away when you point currentSettings at settings.  With ARC enabled I don't think it's leaking memory (the empty dictionary will be released), but it's not doing anything, either.

Comment: where is this different to H2CO3 answer?

Comment: It's not, really, his answer wasn't there when I started typing.

Comment: so you must be a slow typer, he was nearly 3 min faster.

Comment: Quite slow, as a matter of fact.  I also started writing a paragraph about using `setDictionary:` to copy the contents of a dictionary, but decided it wasn't really relevant to the question.